# Javascript + and string return value from function?

Tags: javascript, string, return-value, concatenation

This is a stupid noob issue that just pisses me off .. sorry.

- This works: `alert('hello');`
- This works: `alert(getsomestring());`
- This works: `alert('hello'+'goodbye')`
- So why doesn't this work: `alert('hello'+getsomestring());`

I tried these with no luck:

```
alert('hello'+getsomestring(););
alert('hello'+getsomestring().toString(););
```

thanks.

using it as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getQueryString() { 
    var assoc = new Array(); 
    var queryString = unescape(location.search.substring(1)); 
    var keyValues = queryString.split('&'); 
    for (var i in keyValues) { 
        var key = keyValues[i].split('='); 
        assoc[key[0]] = key[1]; 
    } 
    return assoc; 
} 



</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
alert('?h='+getQueryString()["search"];);
//localSearchHighlight('?h='+getQueryString()["search"]); 
);

</script>
```

Comment: Remember, the error console is your friend. Whenever your JS doesn't work, look into the console. It lists the encountered errors for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors, in the second `<script>` block. It should read:

```
alert('?h='+getQueryString()["search"]);
```

- There was a `;` *inside* the function call parens.
- You had an additional line with `);` after your comment.

Other than that, it seems to work like you want it too.

Comment: I've also tried his code and removed the syntax errors you mentioned. But I kept receiving "?h=undefined".

Comment: He's reading the query string, so append something like `?search=foobar` to the URL (even if it is a local `file://` URI).

Comment: Ahh! You're right. I was trying to append `?h=foobar` and not `?search=foobar`. :P Indeed, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your browser's error console; `alert('hello'+getsomestring();)` is a syntax error due to the semicolon. Semicolons separate lines and shouldn't appear in expressions. Remove it, and the expressions will work (as you have it typed at first: `alert('hello'+getsomestring());`).

Answer (score 0):

There are **no** associative arrays in JavaScript. Only [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects) map keys to values.

Replace `var assoc = new Array();` with `var assoc = new Object();` or the shorthand `var assoc = {};` then it works.

Also there's an superflous `;` in your alert:

```
alert('?h='+getQueryString()["search"];);
                                      ^ --------- SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Comment: Good point, though not actually the error. Array inherits from Object, so his code will still work.

Comment: Still, it will explode as soon as the url is something like `?length=0`.